# Dynamic Programming Fibonacci algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm working on an algorithm to calculate a Fibonacci number and got the pseudo code for it but I can't figure out how much time it takes to run. I think it runs at O(n) but not quite sure.
Here is the code:

```
Algorithm Fast-Fibonacci(n)
Let fib[0] and fib[1] be 1.
for each i from 2 to n, do:
    Let fib[i] be fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1].
end of loop
return fib[n].
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that this takes O(n) as you are just counting sequentially from 2 to n to fill your array.  If you were doing some sort of lookup for each of the i-1 and i-2 numbers, that could increase complexity, but the way you have written it, you are calling a direct address for each of those values.

Answer (score 2):

Yep.  The big giveaway is that you have a constant number of operations per loop and the size of your loop is linear against the size of n.

A more space-efficient solution exists, however, since you don't particularly care about any numbers other than the last two.  Try that next!

Comment: No! The loop is linear against $n$, not against the *size* of $n$, which is $log n$.

Answer (score 1):

Iterative solution to find the nth fibonnaci takes O(n) in terms of the value of n and O(2^length(n)) in terms of the size of n ( length(n) == number of bits to represent n). This kind of running time is called Pseudo-polynomial. However, if recursive method is used to find the fib of n, then it will take exponential time in terms of the value(O(2^n)). But this can be reduced by using dynamic programming approach to solve the fib of n.